# iOS : How to create .a file of Unity 3d export?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have to integrate my unity 3d export into my existing native iOS app (Objective-C) So, need to create the static library of unity export but unable to create.

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and Unity 5.5.1f1.

Is there any alternative other than the following tutorials?

http://matthewhx.blogspot.in/2013/11/unity3d-xcode-project-integrates-with.html
https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same issue